# Invalid pointer issue in insertion sort in ARM assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I'm trying to translate a simple insertion sort algorithm to assembly, but something about this particular configuration is causing the program to get an `invalid pointer` error.

Here's the C version that I'm using:

```
int n, array[100], c, d, t;
for (c = 1; c < n - 1; c++) {
    d = c;
    while (d > 0 && array[d] < array[d - 1]) {
        t = array[d];
        array[d] = array[d - 1];
        array[d - 1] = t;
        d--;
    }
}
```

This is a C struct that is being used:

```
typedef struct { 
    int *list;
    int size;
    int maxSize;
} list;
```

Here is my assembly file:

```
.syntax unified

.text

.align 8
.global insert_ARM
.func insert_ARM, insert_ARM
.type insert_ARM, %function

insert_ARM:
    push {r4-r11, ip, lr}

@ setup
    ldr r4, [r0, #4]
    sub r4, r4, 1    @ r4 = n-1
    mov r5, #1       @ c=1
    mov r6, #16      @ d=0, which starts at #16
    mov r7, #0       @ t=0

for:

   @ d = c ; needs these lines to do the assembly equivalent, which is * 4.
    mov r6, r5      @ d = c
    LSL r6, #2      @ uses logical shift left: multiplies r6 by 4 to get the correct index
    add r6, r6, 16  @ add 16 because that's where the array starts

while:

    @ condition 1: d > 0
    cmp r6, #0      @ if d <= 0, get out of there
    ble forLoopStatements

    @ condition 2: array[d] < array[d-1]
    @ first, I need to define array[d] and array[d-1]
    @ r8 = array[d] and r9 = array[d-1]
    sub r10, r6, #4 @ r10 = d-1
    ldr r9, [r0, r10]   @ r9 = array[d-1]
    ldr r8, [r0, r6]    @ r8 = array[d]
    cmp r9, r8      @ comparing array[d-1] with array[d]
    bge forLoopStatements   @ if array[d] >= array[d-1], get out of there

    @ while effects
    @ note that r8 should still be array[d] here.
    str r9, [r0, r6]    @ array[d] = array[d-1]
    str r8, [r0, r10]   @ array[d-1] = t @ BUG HERE.

    sub r6, r6, #4  @ d--; // does -4 for ARM
    bal while       @ repeat loop


forLoopStatements:
    @ (c<n-1; c++)
    add r5, r5, #1  @ c++
    cmp r5, r4      @ compares c with n-1
    blt for     @ if c < n-1, loop again


end:
    mov r0, r10

    pop {r4-r11, ip, lr}

    BX lr
.endfunc

.end
```

It seems to be

```
str r8, [r0, r10]   @ array[d-1] = t
```

that causes a trip at some point.

Edit: I found out that r8's numbers during this instruction are somehow incorrect, since immediately using something like

```
mov r8, #4
```

before the store prevents the error (but of course makes the results incorrect).

Upon examining the contents of r0, it happens that the update is going off range because other members of the struct are being modified in the process. Array index 0 is at +16.

Comment: Use a debugger to check value of `r0` and `r8` at that point and determine which is wrong. Then figure out how it got that value. It's unclear what your struct is and where `r0` is pointing. You say it contains a pointer to an array, but instead it has some index?

Comment: typedef struct { int *list; int size; int maxSize; } list;

so *list is in r0. I'm trying to modify it with the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Then you are missing the load of the `list` member. Also, what's `sortedList_index_0` and why does it have an offset of `16`?

Comment: It needs to be 16 because that's where the first element of list is.
Size is at +4, maxSize is at +8, +12 is some sort of blank, list[0] is +16, list[1] is +20, etc. I'll update my assembly code with my latest attempt, which should be more straight-forward yet has the same algorithm and the same problem.

Comment: Given your `struct` definition that is probably just accidental that you found the `list[0]` at `+16`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the problem in the translation to assembly. Note however the following problems:

- The outer loop should run all the way to `c < n` instead of `c < n - 1`.  As coded, the last element of the array is never moved.
- it would be more readable to use 2 nested `for` loops:

  ```
  int n, array[100], c, d, t;
  for (c = 1; c < n; c++) {
      for (d = c; d > 0 && array[d] < array[d - 1]; d--) {
          t = array[d];
          array[d] = array[d - 1];
          array[d - 1] = t;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Every one has a different approach to writting code. Mine is different from your, but I would like to share my ideas. I would start with as simple as possible to get somthing working and build from there. Here is a sample code for a forloop.

```
/* forloop.s */

/* int n, array[100], c, d, t;
   for (c=1; c<n-1; c++)
   address of array = r0 = .word ( Raspbian Jessie = 32 bits )
   n = r4 = array size
   c = r5 = 1word = 4memory_bytes = index into array
   d = r6 = c = address in array
   array[d] = r10 = data
*/

.data

.balign 4
array:
    .word 6, 3, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 9, 4
size:
    .word (size - array)

.text

.global main

main:
    push  {r4-r12, lr}        @ save registers for OS
    ldr   r0, =array          @ load address of array in r0
    ldr   r4, =size           @ load address of size in r4
    ldr   r4, [r4]            @ load size in r4
    sub   r4, #4              @ substract 1 word from r4 (n=n-1)
    mov   r5, #4              @ move 4 in r5 (c=1word=4memory_bytes)

for:                          @ (c=1; c<n-1; c++)

    add   r6, r0, r5          @ d (r6) = array address (r0) + (c=4)
@ while:                      @ while loop would go here
    ldr   r10, [r6], #-4      @ r10 = array[d], d=d-4
    ldr   r11, [r6]           @ r11 = array[d-1]
    @...  @ while code
    cmp   r0,  r6             @ is d > 0 ...
    @...  @continue while loop code

    @ back to forloop code
    cmp   r5, r4              @ compare (subtract) r5 (c) from r4 (n)
    add   r5, #4              @ add 1 word to r5 (c++)
    blt   for                 @ end of for loop (c<n-1)

end:
    mov   r0, #0              @ set exit code
    pop   {r4-r12, lr}        @ restore enviroment for return to OS
    bx    lr                  @ return to OS
```

Assemble and link the code and the run it and check ending status.

```
as -o forloop.o forloop.s
gcc -o forloop forloop.o
./forloop; echo $?
```

It works for me on the Raspberry Pi. I don't know much about `gdb`, but this may help as suggested by Jester. (See middle section "Commands" at http://cs107e.github.io/guides/gdb/ for more information.)

```
pi@RPi0:~/pgm/Asm $ gdb -tui forloop  # Text User Interface
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit--- [Enter]
(gdb) layout asm
(gdb) start        @ start is required
(gdb) layout reg
(gdb) Ctl-x o      @ Selects registers as Up & Down arrow to see all
(gdb) si           @ single step
(gdb) [Enter]      @ repeat single step
(gdb) run          @ run program to end
(gdb) q            @ quit gdb
```

Move the down arrow to see the `cpsr` register. The left most number is the flags `8=Negative, 6=Zero&Carry, 4=Zero, 2=Carry, 1=oVerflow`.

Another approach to debugging assembly program on arm is to use the linux printf command. Here is myprint.s.

```
/* myprint.s */

.data

.balign 4
format:
    .asciz " %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d\n"

.balign 4
array:
    .word 6, 3, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 9, 4
size:
    .word (size - array)

.text

.global main

print:    @ --- a printf function to print the value in the array ---
    push  {r0-r12, lr}        @ save registers for OS
    mrs   r10,  cpsr          @ save flag settings
    ldr   r11,  =array        @ To print the array[0-8], the array
    ldm   r11,  {r1-r9}       @  address is loaded in r11 and stored
    push  {r4-r10}            @  in reg r1-r9, printf gets args# from
    ldr   r0,   =format       @  format, 3 print from r1-r3, rest from
    bl    printf              @  stack.
    pop   {r4-r10}            @ adjust stack, restore r10 (flags)
    msr   cpsr_f, r10         @ restore saved flags
    pop   {r0-r12, pc}        @ restore reg and return

main:
    push  {r4-r12, lr}        @ save registers for OS
    bl    print               @ --- can be placed anywhere in code ---
    ldr   r0, =array          @ load address of array in r0
    ldr   r4, =size           @ load address of size in r4
    ldr   r4, [r4]            @ load size in r4
    sub   r4, #4              @ substract 1word from r4 (n=n-1)
    mov   r5, #4              @ move 4 in r5 (c=1word=4memory_bytes)

for:                          @ (c=1; c<n-1; c++)
    add   r6, r0, r5          @ d=r6 = array address (r0) + (c=4)

while:                        @ while loop would go here
    ldr   r10, [r6], #-4      @ r10 = array[d], d=d-4
    ldr   r11, [r6]           @ r11 = array[d-1]
    cmp   r10, r11            @ is array[d] < array[d-1]
    bge   forloop_code        @ if not, continue forloop code
    mov   r7,  r11            @ move array[d-1] into t (r7)
    str   r10, [r6], #4       @ store array[d] into array[d-1], (d-1)+4=d
    str   r7,  [r6], #-4      @ store t-array[d-1] into array[d], d-4=(d-1)
    cmp   r6,  r0             @ is d>0 (addr(array[d-1]) > addr(array[0]))?
    bgt   while               @ yes, check if array[d-1] < array[d-2]

forloop_code:                 @ back to forloop code
    bl    print               @ --- can be placed anywhere in code ---
    cmp   r5, r4              @ compare (subtract) r5 (c) from r4 (n)
    add   r5, #4              @ add 1 word to r5 (c++)
    blt   for                 @ end of for loop (c<n-1)

end:
    pop   {r4-r12, lr}        @ restore registers for OS
    mov   r0, #0              @ set exit code
    bx    lr                  @ return to OS


as -o myprint.o myprint.s
gcc -o myprint myprint.o
./myprint; echo $?
  6   3   7   8   5   2   1   9   4
  3   6   7   8   5   2   1   9   4
  3   6   7   8   5   2   1   9   4
  3   6   7   8   5   2   1   9   4
  3   5   6   7   8   2   1   9   4
  2   3   5   6   7   8   1   9   4
  1   2   3   5   6   7   8   9   4
  1   2   3   5   6   7   8   9   4
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0
```

Another thought would be to assemble your `C` code and use `gdb` to see how C code in assembly. This was an interesting projects, I did not know about insertion sort.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Aside from cleaning up my code, I just needed to translate

```
while ( d > 0 )
```

as

```
cmp r6, #16      @ if d <= 0, get out of there
ble forLoopStatements
```

instead of

```
cmp r6, #0      @ if d <= 0, get out of there
ble forLoopStatements
```

to keep the minimum index at 0.